# send parameters from anchor tag in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a cartname as a link in the table. Onclick of the link, I need to pass the cartname that i clicked to the another angular controller. When I use ng-model and bind the cartname, I am loosing the scope. Any sample code.

Below is the anchor tag,
{{ci.cartname}}

Comment: please share more code, html, controller...

Comment: You probably want to check out `ng-click ()`

Comment: <a ng-href="/PDQServices/#/cartDetails" ng-model="ci.cartname">{{ci.cartname}} </a>

Comment: please find the anchor tag above

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you're trying to share some consistent state across controllers as you're moving throughout the application, you will want to use services to store that data and business logic.  Services are singletons and therefore will maintain state as you're moving through different routes.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `<a ng-click="addItem(ci.cartName)">Add to cart</a>`

Your addItem function would look something like:

```
var items = [];

function addItem(item) {
    items.push(item)
}
```

Should get you on the right path

Comment: I just tried your approach. On click of the link nothing is happening.

Comment: Please find my code I html:<td> <a ng-click="getCartDetails(ci.cartName)">{{ci.cartname}} </a></td>

Comment: Could you show a snippet of your HTML & how you are rendering your elements on the page please

Comment: <tr data-ng-repeat="ci in cartItemsarr | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:paginate">
<td> 
<input type = "checkbox" ng-model="ci.selected" title="Select Cart" checked ="checkBoxValue" value={{ci.cartname}}"> 
</td>
<td> <a ng-href="/CDServices/#/cartDetails" ng-model="ci.cartname">{{ci.cartname}} </a></td>

<td>  {{ci.vendor}}  </td>

<td>  {{ci.status}}   </td>

<td> {{ci.lastModifiedDate}} </td>

<td> {{ci.quantity}}  </td>

</tr>

Comment: In your getCartDetails function when you click it if you console log out the item param do you get anything back?